# Migrate a data block to resource block in Terraform

Tags: terraform

Initially resources in our authentication provider were created manually through the provider web console. It worked and things went to production this way. The problem is that the configuration is increasing in complexity and I'd like to manage it through terraform files instead of continuing through the provider Web console (no backup, no way to recreate everything easily , etc.)

I initially thought of modelling my configuration with data block for the existing resources and use new resources block for the new resources we need to create. Then I wanted to migrate from the data blocks to terraform managed resources (aka resource block). Is it possible through `moved` block or something else? Is it possible to do it without having to recreate a new managed resource and destroy the data resource which is most likely to cause down time or disruption to the end-user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to manage the resources which were initially created manually or out of terraform scope by any means, Terraform cli offers [import](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import) as a native solution by Hashicorp.

Every resource has its own way of importing syntax (starting with `terraform import` ) which you can find at the bottom of any terraform resource definition.

**As an example:**
[Azurerm windows_virtual_machine Import](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_virtual_machine#import)

```bash
terraform import azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.example /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/mygroup1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/machine1
```

**Downside of Native import:** You have to import all resources one by one and sometimes just for one resource(solution) you have to make multiple import calls

as an example for a windows virtual machine, you might import

- azurerm_virtual_machine_extension
- azurerm_managed_disk
- azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment
  as separate. It strongly depends on how would you like them to manage them at the end.

**BUT**

There are few open-source tools available that help If you have lots of resources that you want to bring under terraform management in a lot easier and faster way.

If you working with Azure resources then [aztfy](https://github.com/Azure/aztfy) is the recommended tool as it is natively from Azure.

It does generate the terraform code, additionally, it has a feature where you can import the azure resource group, it automatically imports and generates config for the resources that the resource group is holding. Not to mention but the tool gives you a nice terminal-based-UI experience.

For other hyperscalers, there are two choices.

[terracognita](https://github.com/cycloidio/terracognita): can generate modules too as per their docs.

[terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer): Developed by Google people but not an official product.